# Do python modules get imported twice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

If I have one file that runs `import math`, and a second file that also has `import math` AND which imports the first file, does that load the `math` module twice in memory?

Comment: Python import aren't imported multiple times, if you want to import again you can use [reload()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload)

Comment: @KobiK - `reload` was removed in Python 3.x.  In Python 3.2 or later, you can use [`imp.reload`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/imp.html#imp.reload).

Comment: @iCodez +1 you are right, sorry  I'm still dragging python 2.7 :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do `import math` it is imported and put into `sys.modules`. Next you do `import math` it is checked if `math` is in `sys.modules` and fetched from there.

So it is imported only once.

http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm

> When Python imports a module, it first checks the module registry
> (sys.modules) to see if the module is already imported. If that’s the
> case, Python uses the existing module object as is.
>
> Otherwise, Python does something like this:
>
> 1. Create a new, empty module object (this is essentially a dictionary)
> 2. Insert that module object in the sys.modules dictionary
> 3. Load the module code object (if necessary, compile the module first)
> 4. Execute the module code object in the new module’s namespace. All variables assigned by the code will be available via the module object.
>
> This
> means that it’s fairly cheap to import an already imported module;
> Python just has to look the module name up in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Modules are imported once. The second time that

```
import math
```

is encountered, all that happens is that the already imported module is bound to the name math in the importing module's namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Python modules are not imported multiple times, so running the `import` statement command twice will not reload the module.

If you want it to be reloaded, you have to execute the [reload](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) statement.

Comment: That could have been a comment, look above.