# Is importing same module necessary in other files?

Tags: python

I got 2 modules, both in same directory. I am importing `twitter` package twice.
<s>In my main **TwitterAnalyzert.py** and in **LibOverrider.py** and I really dislike this solution. I want to keep this in seperate files, becouse it may get bigger.</s>

I run `TwitterAnalyzert.py` first, and then override some methods in `twitter` module.

> [Do python modules get imported twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219456/do-python-modules-get-imported-twice)
>
> I found this topic. Answer: `When you do import math it is imported and put into sys.modules. Next you do import math it is checked if math is in sys.modules and fetched from there.`

Looking at the other topic, I should not worry about importing twice. But I got that feeling that something is not right. I wonder if there is any conclusion to this.

Why I must import in every file? I import `twitter` before importing and executing `overrider()` and it is missing anyway: `NameError: name 'twitter' is not defined`.

Importing once --> **Fail**

Importing 2 times --> **It is OK** and overrides correctly

```
# Tree
.
|--Readme.md
|--\TwitterAnalyzer
   |--LibOverrider.py
   |--TwitterAnalyzer.py
   |--__init__.py  # empty file
```

```
# LibOverrider.py
import twitter  # <-- I want to get rid of this

def overrider():
    def show_user_items(self):
        return self.__dict__.items()

    twitter.User.items = show_user_items
    print("Added twitter.User.items")
```

```
# TwitterAnalyzer.py

import twitter  # <-- I import this firsts
import json
from LibOverrider import overrider

overrider()  # <-- overriding methods in twitter module

... # rest of code
```

Comment: You need to import so that the imported name is defined at the current module.

Comment: The `import` is needed in your `LibOverrider.py` because it has no way of knowing what `twitter` is.  It'll fail at the point of `from LibOverrider import overrider` due to `NameError`.  Unless `overrider` is defined within a namespace that contains `twitter` you'll need to dedicate an import within the module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing a module does two important things: it "loads" the module, and it *binds it to the current module's namespace*. That second piece is what you're missing if you don't do the import in the second module. So although the `twitter` module is still "loaded", nothing in the `LibOverrider` module would know how to access it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, that explains everything. Looks like importing is easiest way of binding namespace.